# Multiple LoadDocument for the same DocumentId in indexes and transformers

Tags: ravendb

Let's take simple index from RavenDb documentation as an example:

```
public class SampleIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Invoice>
{
    public SampleIndex()
    {
        Map = invoices => from invoice in invoices
                          select new
                          {
                              CustomerId = invoice.CustomerId,
                              CustomerName = LoadDocument<Customer>(invoice.CustomerId).Name
                          };
    }
}
```

Let's assume I need to have multiple customer properties in the index or transformer. Should I call `LoadDocument<Customer>(invoice.CustomerId).SomeProperty` every time (may be RavenDb optimizes it and actually load document once) or is there any special syntax (similar to `let` in LINQ)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LoadDocument is cached, so calling it once or multiple times for the same document doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.Include<Customer>(invoice => invoice.CustomerId)` with your query, so all referenced customers are returned with the result. See [Load with Includes](http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/client-api/session/loading-entities#load-with-includes).

Comment: Although this is possible with conventional querying, he's asking this question regarding an index which doesn't support `Include()` as far as I'm aware.